# Fluid menu element with image from page resources?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x

I've created a new fluid menu element and I need it to show an image for each page. The image is stored in the page resources.

When I debug the template, each menu item shows `data.media => 1` but media cannot be expanded any further. How can I get the image to render in my template?

TS:

```
ext_menu_image < lib.contentElement
ext_menu_image {
    templateName = MenuImage
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
           special = directory
           special.value.field = pages
           levels = 1
           as = menuItems
           expandAll = 1
           titleField = nav_title // title
        }
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<f:for each="{menuItems}" as="page">
  {f:uri.image(image:page.data.media.???)}
</f:for>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the MenuProcessor just puts the data directly from the table into the array in Fluid. The `media` field in the pages table, just holds the number of relations. So you need another data processor so it is translated to a file. This should do it:

```
ext_menu_image < lib.contentElement
ext_menu_image {
    templateName = MenuImage
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
           special = directory
           special.value.field = pages
           levels = 1
           as = menuItems
           expandAll = 1
           titleField = nav_title // title
           dataProcessing {
             10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
             10 {
               references.fieldName = media
             }
           }
        }
    }
}
```